# Force a new row to start with css grids

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

Consider this situation, which I imagine is a fairly commonplace scenario:

I have a css grid, with 10 columns.
On some rows I am going to want to display content in two columns, or five columns, or maybe all 10.
The default behavior seems to be to flow the columns to fill the row, so that if I wanted a row with 6 columns of content, and then a new row underneath with 7 columns of content, it would actually just flow so that I have a row with 10 columns of content and then underneath the next row would have 3 columns of content.

How can I insert a breaker, to ensure that the 7 columns of content start on the next row, so that the resulting grid would be:

`Row 1: 6 cols of content, 4 empty cols`

`Row 2: 7 cols of content, 3 empty cols`

Please note: I am aware of `grid-row-start` property but I want this to be dynamic, I do not want to have to manually adjust this property whenever I add / remove content.
I am also aware that I could open a new div with `display: grid` for each new row, but again, seems as though I should be able to achieve this layout without either of the above solutions.

What would be the best practice way of doing this?

Answer (score 12):

I have found a way to achieve this now.

Specify the column start number on the column cell level that you want to be the first column of the new row.

Example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  background-color: grey;
}

.single-col {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: orange;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

.new-row {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>

  <div class="single-col new-row">One Col - new row</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>
  <div class="single-col">One Col</div>

</div>
```